# Set different connector in FixedTimeline in timelines flutter package

Tags: flutter

I am using [timelines](https://pub.dev/packages/timelines) flutter package. In that FixedTimeline I want to set different connector color as shown here:

[image: Flipkart order tracking]

So I tried the following code:

```html
FixedTimeline.tileBuilder(
     theme: TimelineTheme.of(context).copyWith(
     nodePosition: 0,
     connectorTheme: ConnectorThemeData(color: Colors.green),
     indicatorTheme: IndicatorThemeData(color: Colors.red),
  ),
  builder: TimelineTileBuilder.connectedFromStyle(
  contentsAlign: ContentsAlign.basic,
  connectorStyleBuilder: (context, index) => ConnectorStyle.solidLine,
  indicatorStyleBuilder: (context, index) => IndicatorStyle.dot,
  firstConnectorStyle: ConnectorStyle.transparent,
  lastConnectorStyle: ConnectorStyle.transparent,
  contentsBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
                           padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
                           child: Text('Timeline Event $index'),
                        ),
           itemCount: 2,
     ),
  ),
```

but I got the following output:

[image: ShopApp]

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify `indicatorStyleBuilder` right now you just saying to use dot with default values

```
indicatorStyleBuilder: (context, index) => IndicatorStyle.dot(
  color: (index == 0) ? Colors.green : Colors.blue,
)
```

of course your logic will be more complex than that but this should be a good starting point

Comment: wrong answer, I think. The expression IndicatorStyle.dot doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked. IndicatorStyle is an enum.

Comment: for a more constructive feedback, please find a proposed working solution in my separate answer :)

Comment: @Marc https://github.com/chulwoo-park/timelines/blob/7be49590321c2b3f6e06d67c3b4b196c11cc23e8/lib/src/indicators.dart#L46

Comment: yes but this doesn't return a indicatorStyleBuilder, which is what we need.

Comment: I may have missed something though. My proposed code above works but can you please share a min reproducible piece of code as well, using the TimelineTileBuilder.connectedFromStyle builder?

Answer (score 0):

After diving into the `timelines` source code on GitHub, I found the answer to your question.

First, let's note that your objective cannot be achieved by using the `builder` as it is: a `TimelineTileBuilder.connectedFromStyle`. Why? Because the package authors have not implemented this specific method just yet. You can find in the source code a clear `TODO` note right next to the Containerized version of the `IndicatorStyle` enum (the container `child` implementation is currently missing, at the time of my answer here). Your `indicatorStyleBuilder: (context, index) => IndicatorStyle.dot` approach, although a good idea, cannot work, as not implemented behind the scenes.

Now, there is still a way to implement exactly what you need, just by using another type of `builder`: the `TimelineTileBuilder.connected` one.

Your code would then become:

```
FixedTimeline.tileBuilder(
  theme: TimelineTheme.of(context).copyWith(
    nodePosition: 0,
    connectorTheme: ConnectorThemeData(color: Colors.green),
    indicatorTheme: IndicatorThemeData(color: Colors.red),
  ),
  builder: TimelineTileBuilder.connected(
    contentsAlign: ContentsAlign.basic,
    oppositeContentsBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
        child: Text('Opposite Timeline Event $index'),
      );
    },
    connectorBuilder: (context, index, type) {
      return SolidLineConnector(
        color: Colors.green,
      );
    },
    indicatorBuilder: (context, index) {
      return DotIndicator(
        color: Colors.red,
      );
    },
    itemCount: 2,
  ),
)
```

This alternative works well for me.